# How to represent an ES6 Map in a Mongoose.js Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, ecmascript-6, mongoose-schema

I'm using an ES6 Map for the "specs" property, which I've represented as seen below in my TypeScript interface:

```
import { IModel } from './model';

export interface IProduct extends IModel {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  specs: {[key: string]: string };
  img: string[];
}
```

That doesn't seem to work in the mongoose Schema, though. After that failed, I tried the below code in my Schema, which doesn't seem to work either:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  specs: [{key: String, value: String}],
  img: String[]
});
```

If someone could help me figure out the correct way to do this, I would be very grateful.

Comment: What was the problem you've encountered with second snippet? If a map isn't supposed to be searchable, it likely should be an array of key/value pairs. If it is, then specs should likely be moved to separate collection and referenced.

Comment: @estus - Hi, and thanks for the response. The problem with the second snippet is that the Schema is expecting an array of key:value pairs, but an ES6 Map is actually an object with an array of key:value pairs (as the TS interface reflects), but writing it this way doesn't work: `{ [ {key: String, value: String} ] }`. Writing it that way actually results in a compiler error. That is why I attempted writing it the way shown in my original post, but when I run the app it doesn't work. I will try moving it to a separate collection, as you recommend.

Comment: I guess you need to stick to an array of key/value arrays and do `Array.from(specsMap)` and `new Map(specsArray)` transforms before and after requests. This could be handled by a plugin if you use it a lot. Probably deserves an issue on Mongoose tracker.